# Error: load_weights requires h5py when loading weights from HDF5

Tags: keras, h5py

I used both commands below and received a message about being successful install and restarting the kernel

- conda uninstall h5py
- pip install h5py

But still, get this error below:

> ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14156/3723649668.py in 1 import
> tensorflow as tf 2 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
> tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, input_shape=(3,)),
> tf.keras.layers.Softmax()]) ----> 3
> model.load_weights('my_weights.h5')
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in
> load_weights(self, filepath, by_name, skip_mismatch, options) 2344
> status = None 2345 if h5py is None: -> 2346 raise ImportError( 2347
> 'load_weights requires h5py when loading weights from HDF5.') 2348 if
> not self._is_graph_network and not self.built:
>
> ImportError: load_weights requires h5py when loading weights from
> HDF5.

Comment: Did you try importing the h5py library? You will probably notice that it errors.

Comment: Thanks, I installed h5py successfully using Anaconda but still I get the below error.

Comment: ImportError: `load_weights` requires h5py when loading weights from HDF5.

Comment: That is not what I asked, can you import h5py successfully in a python shell?